# How can I code markers for different groups' values over a period of time?

Tags: plotting, dataset

I have a 3-column dataset where I show the probabilities of winning of teams in different years (team name, year, prob.)

I need to plot it with markers so the probabilities of each team can be identified over this period of time. This is how I coded the plot:

```
MLSscatter = 
  MLSdata[
    ListPlot[Tooltip[#], 
      PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
      AxesLabel -> {"Year", "Prob"}, 
      ImageSize -> 700,
      PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Large]}] &, 
    {#Year, #Prob} &]
```

I assume I have to give the `PlotMarkers -> Automatic` some extra instructions to consider the column "team name", but I do not know how. Can somebody give me a hand with this?

Here it is a sample of the dataset:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o6Z8TyOk8qrfDidKUUPIhSDmxGF0no0AGtBvj8oEGks/edit?usp=sharing

```
Team    Year    Probability
Colorado Rapids 2004    0.347327073
Dallas  2004    0.337920147
San Jose    2004    0.35962753
Los Angeles Galaxy  2004    0.39816025
Kansas City 2004    0.384930343
Average 2004    0.365593069
Chivas  2005    0.228527286
Colorado Rapids 2005    0.346717
Dallas  2005    0.405828388
San Jose    2005    0.420191143
Los Angeles Galaxy  2005    0.39360505
R. Salt Lake    2005    0.260887715
Average 2005    0.342626097
Chivas  2006    0.328711988
Colorado Rapids 2006    0.354479334
Dallas  2006    0.417429584
Houston 2006    0.393905569
Los Angeles Galaxy  2006    0.34447955
R. Salt Lake    2006    0.284803141
Average 2006    0.353968194
Chivas  2007    0.38657813
Colorado Rapids 2007    0.341129973
Dallas  2007    0.38977568
Los Angeles Galaxy  2007    0.352687067
R. Salt Lake    2007    0.265266957
Houston 2007    0.406474713
Average 2007    0.35698542
Houston 2008    0.414484773
Chivas  2008    0.377620317
R. Salt Lake    2008    0.32784385
Colorado Rapids 2008    0.346302497
Dallas  2008    0.352971193
San Jose    2008    0.281366727
Los Angeles Galaxy  2008    0.36859292
Average 2008    0.352740325
```

Comment: To come up with an answer, most of us, would want to run tests with your code and your data. But you give us code without a sample of your data. Do you expect us to manufacture our the data our own? I think you are unlikely to get an answer unless you edit your question to include a sample of the data needed to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It is the first time I use this website and I do not really know how it works. You should be able to access the dataset now with the link. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you copy your data and import it, e.g. using `data = ImportString["yourdatahere", "TSV"][[2;;]]`, then the following should work for you:

```
ListPlot[
 GroupBy[data, First -> (Tooltip[Rest[#], First[#]] &)], 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 14},
 AxesLabel -> {"Year", "Prob"},
 PlotStyle -> Blue
]
```

[image: according to original request]

In the expression `data = ImportString["yourdatahere", "TSV"][[2;;]]`, the `[[2;;]]` is there to get rid of the headers, i.e. the first row of your dataset.

I could not interpret what you meant in your `ListPlot` syntax. The key of your problem, i.e. assigning tooltips to markers, and grouping performance by year, are taken care of by the following:

```
 GroupBy[data, First -> (Tooltip[Rest[#], First[#]] &)]
```

This parses your data, grouping it in an association object by the first element of each row (i.e. the team name); the values in this association are also decorated via tooltips bearing the name of the team. These tooltips will be honored by `ListPlot`, so you'll see that if you mouseover any of your plot markers in the plot above the name of the corresponding team will appear in a pop up.

Note also that `PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[Large]}` will assign the `Blue` style to the first data series in your plot, the `Large` style to the second, and so on. If you want to assign them both to all data series, you will want to wrap them in Directive, i.e. `PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, PointSize[Large]]`. Even then, size of the markers is best controlled through PlotMarkers directly, i.e. `PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, yourDesiredSize}`; this will also apply variable coloring, so if you want to maintain the blue coloring throughout, you want to follow that with `PlotStyle -> Blue`, as I did above.

Finally, I'd suggest the following to take advantage of color as well:

```
ListPlot[
 GroupBy[data, First -> (Tooltip[Rest[#], First[#]] &)],
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"Year", "Probability"}),
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 18}
]
```

[image: in color]

---

In response to the comment asking to highlight one team by connecting the corresponding plot markers, here is an interactive implementation:

```
grouped = GroupBy[data, First -> (Tooltip[Rest[#], First[#]] &)];

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[
  grouped,
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 14},
  AxesLabel -> {"Year", "Prob"},
  PlotStyle -> Blue,
  Prolog -> {
    Red, Thick,
    Line[grouped[team] /. Tooltip[a_, _] :> a]
  }
 ],
 {team, Keys@grouped}
]
```

[image: highlighted team]

If you simply want each team to have its own line connecting the corresponding markers, then the `Joined -> True` option of `ListPlot` is for you:

```
ListPlot[
 GroupBy[data, First -> (Tooltip[Rest[#], First[#]] &)], 
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 14},
 AxesLabel -> {"Year", "Prob"},
 Joined -> True
]
```

[image: joined]

(In this case I would urge the use of colors to distinguish the lines)

Comment: this is a great clear exposition. +2 :)

Comment: This is an awesome explanation! It works perfectly! The "groupby" command was the one I was missing.

Comment: One last thing, is it possible to connect the markers of one team with a line over the years so you can differentiate it from the rest?

Comment: @Karl Take a look at the updated answer, and let me know if either approach fits your need.

Comment: @MarcoB That was it. I'll try it now but it should work. :) Great contribution

Comment: @MarcoB The first approach fits as I only need the average to be differentiated. However, when I try to replicate the following error pops up: Coordinate $CellContext`average[Association["Average" -> {Association["Year" -> 2004, "Probability" -> 0.344668886], Association["Year" -> 2005, "Probability" -> 0.38049507847222225`], Association["Year" -> 2006, "Probability" -> 0.3641287911458333], Association["Y should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form. I use SemanticImport with "team" column as "string". That might be the problem

Comment: @Karl yes I think the format generated by semantic import is different from that expected here, and not particularly useful. Try this instead. Copy your data from your google document (ctrl+c), then use the `ImportString` expression I mentioned in my post: just highlight the `yourdata` placeholder, then paste in your data there. That's what I did to generate the plots shown, so it should work for you too.

Comment: It works indeed. The semantic import was the problem here. Very helpful. Great job @MarcoB. I hope the post helps others too.